# getFileAsync not returning file in Word for iPad

Tags: ms-word, office-js

In my add-in I am calling `getFileAsync()`. When running on Word for iPad, the result being returned is empty.

I am using the following code:

```js
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#run').click(showFileSize);
    });
};

function showFileSize() {
    Office.context.document.getFileAsync('text', function (result) {
        if (result.status === "succeeded") {
            var file = result.value;
            var fileSize = file.size; // file.size is zero when document has some text
            // ...
            file.closeAsync();
        }
    });
}
```

The `result.value` returned contains no data:

```json
{ 
  size: 0, 
  sliceCount: 0 
}
```

I am using iOS version 11.0.2 and Word for iPad version 2.6

What is wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the contents of `result.value` (i.e. `console.log(result.value)`)?

Comment: Hi @MarcLaFleur-Microsoft the contents of `result.value` are `{ size: 0, sliceCount: 0 }`